# How to read graph data using selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to read data from a graph using selenium Webdriver.

The graph on the website looks like:
[image]

If I bring my cursor on top of the dot in red box, a pop up appears which gives the CTR and Impressions value at that date.

I cannot do inspect element on this popup.All in the source code, I am unable to see any text similar to 2,790 Impressions value.

How can I read the value of CTR and impressions corresponding to each date.Please help and suggest.

In HTML, I can only see dates like:

```
<div class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<span style="position: absolute; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif ! important; font-size: 11px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(112, 112, 112); cursor: default; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 1146.69px; top: 256px;" opacity="1"><div style="overflow:hidden;text-align:center;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:81px;">**19/11/2015**</div></div>
```

Kindly suggest.Any help will be appreciated!!

More html:

```
<div id="widget-5665340308297502-inner" class="widget-data menu firepath-matching-node" data-bind="attr:{id: internal.controlWidgetInnerContainerId}, event:{dblclick: api.editSettings}" style="" data-highcharts-chart="3">
<svg version="1.1" style="font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif !important;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1309" height="287">
<div class="highcharts-tooltip" style="position: absolute; left: 146px; top: -9999px; visibility: visible;">
<div class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div>06/11/2015</div>
</span>
</div>
<div class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
</div>
```

Comment: can you post some more HTML ?

Comment: Post a link to the page?